# Whats the best way to update the gradient value in QML from C++?

Tags: c++, qml, gradient

In my QML file I have gradient defined as below:

```
ColorizedRoundedButton
{
   gradient: Gradient   
           {
             GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#3f5c43" }            
             GradientStop { position: 0.33; color: "#113d14" }            
             GradientStop { position: 0.66; color: "#023105" }            
             GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#056508" }    
           }
}
```

So here I want this gradient value to be applied through Stylesheet i.e exactly setting this value from C++.

I have the Style.h file like this:

```
#include <QLinearGradient>

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QLinearGradient)

class Style: public QObject
{
  Q_PROPERTY(QLinearGradient PositiveGradient READ getPositiveGradient WRITE setPositiveGradient)

  QLinearGradient _positiveGradient;
  QLinearGradient getPositiveGradient();
  void setPositiveGradient(QLinearGradient p_grad);
}
```

With this approach of using the QLinearGradient type as Q_PROPERTY and changing the QML file to:

```
gradient: style.PositiveGradient
```

This approach didnt work, I am getting the runtime error as cannot assign QLinearGradient to QQuickGradient*.

Anybody knows the solution for this or any better solution to pass the gradient values between c++ and QML ?

Comment: The error description is clear enough. The `Gradient` from QtQuick is `QQuickGradient` so assigning type of `QLinearGradient` to `QQuickGradient` is incorrect. The class `QQuickGradient` is private and I don't know how to do that without tricks. As a workaround you can pass not the class itself but arrays of numbers(positions and colors) and assign it to `Gradient` item.

Answer (score 0):

Declare Class:

```
class Style: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    
 public:
    explicit Style(QObject *parent = nullptr)
    {}

public slots:
    QStringList stops()
    {
        QLinearGradient gradeint(0, 0, 1, 100);
        gradeint.setColorAt(0, "red");
        gradeint.setColorAt(1, "black");
    
        QStringList colors;
    
        for (const auto &g : gradeint.stops())
        {
            colors.append(g.second.name());
        }
    
        return colors;
    }
};
```

After you wrote this class register it in main and write in qml:

```
Rectangle {
id: root

    gradient: Gradient {
        id:gradient
    }

    Component
    {
        id:stopComponent
        GradientStop {}
    }

    Component.onCompleted:
    {
        var stops = Style.stops()

        var stopsList = [];
        var length = stops.length;

        for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            var s1 = stopComponent.createObject(root, {"position": i / length , "color": stops[i]});
            stopsList.push(s1)
        }
        gradient.stops = stopsList
    }
}
```